# SymPy fails to parse pyomo expression containing multi index variable references

Tags: python, optimization, expression, sympy, pyomo

I'm trying to parse an expression resulting from optimizing a pyomo model using SymPy. The model contains both simple and indexed variable references, which are represented in the resulting expression like this:
simple:
`simple_var`
indexed:
`indexed_var[index_name]` where index_name is a value from a pyomo defined set.

I notice that when trying to parse the resulting expression, SymPy consistently fails with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Blockquote
>
> jacobians = differentiate(model.objective.expr, wrt_list=var_list)
>
> in differentiate    tmp_expr, locals=dict((str(x), x) for x in sympy_vars) )
>
> in sympify   expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
>
> return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
>
> in parse_expr  eval_expr(code, global_dict, local_dict)
>
> TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable

EDIT: This is basically the stacktrace without a lot of local file references

I tried to use pyomo to parse the expression in hopes it will pass on some extra context but the result is the same. 
The only obvious way to move forward for me would be to do some string replacement in the resulting expression, parse it with SymPy, then do some more string parsing after I'm done with SymPy and extract my data from there.

That seems really error prone, so here I am asking if there is a more elegant suggestion.

Comment: What SymPy function are you using to parse? Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It's sort of there in the post, e.g. `S("x[k]")` fails.

Comment: @Desire: How can you be sure that `S`/`sympify` is used? Sympy has [an entire submodule dedicated to parsing](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html). Either way, I don’t like to go through a bunch of candidate functions to see which one produces a matching error.

Comment: it's sympify... i'll update the post with the full stack trace

Comment: You can sanitize it if you'd like, but the local file references might be helpful to see which function in which module is being called. I'm having a hard time following the stacktrace as it's written.

Comment: i ended up sanitizing it..... i think the problem i'm facing now is actually extracting concrete numbers from the parsed expression